# While loop error in java : ')' expected and ';' expected and not a statement ..

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am getting an error that says:
')' expected 
not a statement
 ';' expected
 not a statement

```
while(high=true, p>=10000,y-40;){
    p = p/2;

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: as long as high is true and p is less than 10,000 i want to subtract 40 from y and cut p in half...

Comment: `while (high && p>=10000) { y -= 40; p /= 2; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while loop must have a Boolean expression within the parentheses. For example `high == true`. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with comma separated list.

Your expression would then be `high == true && p < 10000`

Move the subtraction into the body of the loop.

Comment: I just edited my answer and removed the `=` from `<=` because you only said that p must be less than 10000 not less than or equal.